# Svm Classification

Tags: machine-learning

What can be the theoretical reason/s for which a support vector machine with linear kernel (implemented with LinearSVC from sklearn) fails miserably in a multi-class (5 classes) classification?

Comment: Perhaps more suitable in Stat or Crossvalidation.

Answer (score 1):

An SVM assumes that a separating hyperplane classifies your data well.  If no separating hyperplane exists, then an SVM will not perform well.

Or, there's a bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

A Support Vector Machine only separates binarily. Discriminates between *two* classes. Or between belonging or not belonging to one class. For more than two classes you will need to be inventive to get it to make sense.